# Estimate the impact of in-store product placement

Tags: r, regression, mixed-model, random-effects-model, difference-in-difference

I have six variables: sales (weekly), product category, customer segment, store location, week and product placement (aisle, entrance, ...). For each category, segment and location, I observe sales for different product placements. For the first three weeks, I observe "aisle", for weeks 4-6, I observe entrance and so on.

I am trying to estimate whether product placement has an impact on sales and what placement is maximizing sales. Here is a generated sample of my data in R for illustration:

```
library(dplyr)
library(lme4)

product_category <- c("catA", "catB", "catC", "catD", "catE")
customer_segment <- c("custA", "custB", "custC")
store_location <- c("locA", "locB", "locC", "locD")
placement <- c("aisle", "window", "wherever")

df1 <- expand.grid(product_category = product_category, 
               customer_segment = customer_segment, 
               store_location = store_location, 
               placement = placement)

weeks <- rep(1:3, each = 15, times = 4)

df2 <- bind_cols(df1, sales = runif(dim(df1)[1], 10, 100)) 
   %>% 
  arrange(store_location) %>% 
  mutate(weeks = as.factor(weeks))
```

My first idea was to use linear regression and test the significance of product placement. However, my observations are most likely not independent (in terms of time and spatially) and I decided to use a mixed effect model, in which I treat placement as fixed effect and for all the other variables I add a random intercept. I use the lme4 package in R and my code looks as follows:

```
df2 <- df2 %>% mutate_if(is.character, as.factor)

lme4::lmer(sales ~ placement + (1|weeks) + 
          (1|product_category) +  (1|customer_segment) + 
          (1|store_location), data = df2, REML = F)
```

I am new to mixed effect models. Is this an appropriate way of estimating the impact of product placement? Are there alternatives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The model:

```
lmer(sales ~ placement + (1|weeks) + (1|product_category) +  
       (1|customer_segment) + (1|store_location), 
        data = df2, REML = FALSE)
```

seems to be a reasonable approach to this problem, provided that you have more categories, locations and segments than shown in your simulation. A good rule of thumb is 10. 20 is better. 6 is on the cusp of being too few. For the `weeks` variable, it would be better to code this as 1 through however many weeks there are in total, rather than 1-3 repeated (since 3 levels is too few to fit random intercepts).

The model will estimate fixed effects for `placement` which, by default, will provide 2 estimates: each one being the estimated difference in sales between each of these estimates and the reference level for `placement`, along with a global intercept which will contain the reference level for `placement`.

Comment: Can I ask you one more thing. If I want to determine the interaction effect of product category and placement on sales but at the same time, I know that I should model product category as a random effect. How would you proceed? I'm a little bit lost since I think that modeling it as fixed and random effect at the same time does not make sense (apart from running in computational problems). Thank you very much!

Comment: If you have specific interest in the estimate for an interaction involving `product_category` then you would need to fit this as a fixed effect, not random. For example: `sales ~ placement*product_category + (1|weeks) +  (1|customer_segment) + (1|store_location)`

Comment: Thanks a lot! 

Comment: I hope you don't mind asking you one more thing. If you prefer I can also create a new question. Modelling store_location as random intercept seems to cause the residuals to be  distributed very non-normal. When I change store_location to be a fixed effect, this non-normality vanishes. Do you have any idea what is causing this? I would actually prefer to keep store_location as random effect.

Comment: No worries. How many stores do you have ? Are the inferences consistent between both models ? It's probably best to write a new question and post the summary output for both models.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. There are 10 different stores. I‘ll compare the inferences tonight :-)

Comment: The inferences between the models are consistent. Estimates and standard errors are pretty much identical.